# error setting start point from geolocation calc route() gmaps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

i use that code to have the geolocation in my app and it works good also when i'm moving. I added some few lines to create a calculation from the geolocation to an end (fixed) point with fixed lat-long. I don't understand why the origin point in my code is not accepted (fireBug says that i cannot call a property [object Object] on it) but i cannot figure out.
Here are the code about the gmaps v3:

```
//image for the marker
var imageLoc = '../../img/bbb3.gif' 
var map;
//initialize the maps
function initialize() {
  //call directionsService and Display for the route
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  //map option
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.49489, 11.34262),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      mapOptions);
  //create the marker for the geolocation
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
          map: map,
          icon: imageLoc
  });
  //call updatePos() function
  updatePos();

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
      var request = {
        //origin is the marker of my geolocation
        origin: marker,
        //destination is a fxed position
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(44.496099,11.340246),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
}
var i;
//here I set my marker (if i==0 -> first run)
function updatePos(){
var options = {
    timeout: 60000, enableHighAccuracy: true
};
var myUpdatedPos = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
function onSuccess(position) {
    if (i==0){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
                        map: map                       
                    });
    }
    i++;
    //here I update the position
     newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    marker.setPosition(newLatlng);
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Does anyne have idea why?

kind regards

Brus

Comment: Your onSuccess and onError functions are nested within updatePos - is this correct?

Comment: I really don't understand what your onSuccess function is doing - if i = 0, it creates a marker at the position coordinates.  Then it updates the marker, to the same coordinates

Comment: Hi Duncan, when i=0 take the first latlong of my position, create a marker with a custom icon and then update it every 60000 ms.

Answer (score 2):

The directionRequest takes either a string (an "address") or a google.maps.LatLng for origin and destination.  marker is a google.maps.Marker object.

```
var request = {
    //origin is the marker of my geolocation
    origin: marker,
    //destination is a fxed position
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(44.496099,11.340246),
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
 };
```

To get the position of a marker, use its getPosition method:

```
var request = {
    //origin is the marker of my geolocation
    origin: marker.getPosition(),
    //destination is a fxed position
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(44.496099,11.340246),
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
 };
```

To give the marker a position when you initialize it, you can do this:

```
 //create the marker for the geolocation
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
      map: map,
      position: map.getCenter(),
      icon: imageLoc
 });
```

Comment: Hi geocodedzip thanks for your reply. Unfortunately when i call the .getPosition() method it doesn't work. FireBug says "value not valid for <origin> of property: undefined" and i still don't understand why.  Have you got any other suggestion? kind regards

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem

Comment: The first time you call the DirectionsService the position of the marker hasn't been set (updatePos is asynchronous), so marker.getPosition() returns undefined and you get that error.  Only call the directions service after you have set the markers position for the first time.

Comment: Ok i understand, but if i set the marker before the "var mapOption{}" it doesn't appear, i mean appar only the marker static and not the marker with the updatePosition i setted.
 I edited the code calling the direction services after the marker but it still doesn't work. Can you please tell me how to edit my code to have it works?

Comment: This works for me: `
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:map.getCenter(),
        map: map
    });`; [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2LeY/3)/

Comment: I know it works with a static lat-long coordinates of the marker. My point is that i don't understand how to calc the route from my geolocation point who is the start point (updated when i'm moving ) to a marker (with fixed at-long).

Comment: My point is that the error happens the first time you call the directions service; because the marker doesn't have a position (yet).  If you want it to use the first position returned by the geolocation service, then you need to call the directions service after that sets the marker position (in its callback routine).